# Compiling to 32-bit using make

Tags: c, x86, makefile

I am trying to compile a very simple program using the -m32 flag.

 If I try to do this using gcc -m32 it works just fine(I have the needed libs)

Yet, when I add this flag to my flags in a makefile, I get a weird error
This is the makefile that I have

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-m32 -O1 -W -Wall -pedantic -std=c99

all: main.o 
    $(CC) -o main main.o 
    rm main.o 

clean: 
    rm main
```

The error that I receive is the following

```
gcc -o main main.o
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `main.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Can someone please tell me what does this mean? and how can I fix it?

As for the code, the code does NOTHING except printing 'hello world'

I am using GCC 4.4.3 under Linux 2.6.35 64-bits

Comment: can you add the line where you compile main.c to main.o ?

Comment: @TomAhh: make has an [implicit rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html) for compiling `.o` files from `.c` files

Comment: @AdamRosenfield Oh. Ok, sorry about that then. :)

Comment: Since you are relying on the implicit rule to make `main.o`, why not also use the implicit rule to make `main`?  You are not passing `$(CFLAGS)`, but the implicit rule would do so.  Use the implicit rule.

Comment: @WilliamPursell the implicit rule for `main` from `main.o` would invoke the linker with `$(LDFLAGS)` not with `$(CFLAGS)`

Comment: @zakkak If neither rule is explicitly given, the single suffix rule `.c` will be used, which uses both: `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $<`

Comment: @WilliamPursell you are right I didn't think about `main:%.c`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your mistake is that you don't pass `-m32` to the linker.

You actually need to change your `Makefile` to look like this:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-m32 -O1 -W -Wall -pedantic -std=c99
LDFLAGS = -m32

all: main.o 
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o main main.o 
    rm main.o 

clean: 
    rm main
```

An even better approach would be the following `Makefile`:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-m32 -O1 -W -Wall -pedantic -std=c99
LDFLAGS=-m32

.INTERMEDIATE: main.o

all: main

main: main.o

clean: 
    -rm main
```

In the later you just say that main depends on `main.o` and `GNU Make` will invoke the linker with the `LDFLAGS` as arguments for you as it invokes the compiler with the `CFLAGS` as arguments for the `main.o`

"The targets which .INTERMEDIATE depends on are treated as intermediate files. See section Chains of Implicit Rules. .INTERMEDIATE with no dependencies marks all file targets mentioned in the makefile as intermediate." [Special Built-in Target Names](http://theory.uwinnipeg.ca/localfiles/infofiles/make/make_36.html#SEC35)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Though can you please just briefly explain to me what the .INTERMEDIATE: statement does?

Comment: Oh nvm, I think I got it. :D it's responsible for deleting .o files after the compilation/linking is done, right?

Comment: Yes it actually says to `make` which files (of those generated during the `make` execution) are not needed and could be removed. In some cases `make` deletes some files thinking they are intermediate while you want/need them. In such cases you can use .SECONDARY to tell `make to not delete this files. Have a look at the link i provide on the answer.

Answer (score 5):

You should inform the linker as well about the architecture being 32-bit. Try adding

```
LD = $(CC)
LDFLAGS = -m32
```

to your Makefile and change

```
$(CC) -o main main.o
```

to

```
$(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o main $^
```

and it shoud work.

(Why it worked? If you use GCC to compile and link your code in one step, all the relevant flags and options will be passed down not only to the compiler but to the linker as well.)

Comment: Actually it won't work because in his Makefile he doesn't pass the LDFLAGS to the linker.

Comment: @zakkak actually, it's his fault :)

Comment: yes but that didn't make your answer correct ;) nice you fixed it ;)